# Possible to pass in a generic entity and access a common property?

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I want to have a method that checks some AccountIDs are allowed for a certain operations and in doing so, I need to get a distinct list of AccountIDs in any entity type that I pass through.

I could have a User entity, a Transaction entity, and Product entity, etc. but they will all always have an AccountID property no matter what.

This is some non-working code to hopefully give you the gist of what I'm trying to accomplish...

```
public void CheckForAccountAuthorization<T>(IQueryable<T> entityWithAccountIdProperty)
{
    IEnumerable<string> accountIdList 
        = entityWithAccountIdProperty.Select(u => u.AccountID).Distinct();

    //Do More Work...

    }
}
```

But it gives me the errors:

> Unknown method 'Select(?)' of 'System.Linq.IQueryable'
>
> Unknown member 'AccountID' of 'T'

Comment: Have you tried constraining T to be of a common type or interface i.e. public void CheckForAccountAuthorization<T>(IQueryable<T> entityWithAccountIdProperty) where T : MyAccount { ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create some interface with `AccountID` property:

```
public interface IAccount
{
    int AccountID { get; set; }
}
```

And make User entity, Transaction entity, and Product entity implement it:

```
public class User : IAccount
{
    public int AccountID { get; set; }
    // ... 
}
```

Then make [constraint on generic type parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

```
public void CheckForAccountAuthorization<T>(IQueryable<T> accounts)
   where T : IAccount
{
    IEnumerable<string> accountIdList 
        = accounts.Select(u => u.AccountID).Distinct();

    // ...
}
```

Now you have `AccountID` property available.

Comment: I'm having issues call this now. Is there a trick to passing this entity into this method?  `UserInsertModel` implements the `IAccount` interface like you said  `public void InsertUsers(List<UserInsertModel> user)
        {
            CheckForAccountAuthorization(user);
...}`

Comment: @RichC what issued do you have? Is it some compilation error?

Comment: I think this may have fixed it: `CheckForAccountAuthorization((IQueryable<IAccount>)model);`  I'm still testing but the error went away, though.

Comment: @RichC if `User` implements `IAccount` and you have added constraint for method generic parameter T `where T: IAccount` then all should work

Answer (score 0):

Use an interface:

```
interface IAccountable
{
    public int AccountID {get;}
}
```

Then specify it in the generic:

```
public void CheckForAccountAuthorization<T>(IQueryable<T> entityWithAccountIdProperty)
    where T : IAccountable
{
    IEnumerable<string> accountIdList 
        = entityWithAccountIdProperty.Select(u => u.AccountID).Distinct();

    //Do More Work...

    }
}
```